# Flutter moveable Container

Tags: android, flutter

I am searching for a container where I can set an Offset property. Because I want that the Container is moveable. The movement I am doing is with the GestureDetector. Currently I am moving each node individually with Transform. translate. The nodes are in a stack Widget. I am making a simple graph with moving and zooming. The container should take a list of widgets.

Comment: use `Transform` widget as a parent

Comment: [here](https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/example/lib/transform_demo.dart) you have such a demo using `Transform` widget

Comment: Thank you it works.

Comment: sure, your welcome